# Unmodifiable form in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a `Map<String, String>` that I'd like to display to a user but I don't want them to be able to select the field to modify it's value. I've been using a form with textfields and setting setting a property to disable them. This is not ideal as their aesthetics change. Am I doing it the correct way and simply need to apply some css or is their a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a form 'label' which is un-modifiable but looks like the rest of the form. Might need a few tweaks but this should get you started:

```
Ext.form.LabelField = function(config){
   Ext.form.LabelField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};

Ext.extend(Ext.form.LabelField, Ext.form.Field,  {
    isField: true,
    value: '',
    renderSelectors: {fieldEl: '.x-form-labelfield'},
    renderTpl: [
        '<tpl if="label">',
            '<div class="x-form-label"><span>{label}</span></div>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<div class="x-form-label x-form-labelfield" style="width:70%; text-align:right"><span>{value}</span></div>',
   ],
   setValue:function(val) {
      this.value = val;
      if(this.rendered){
         this.fieldEl.update('<span>' + val + '</span>');
      }
    return this;
   },

});

Ext.reg('labelfield', Ext.form.LabelField);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same need and wanted the field to function similar to the ExtJS displayfield. I have done this in Sencha Touch by creating the field, disabling it, then adding back the normal field class. The editor is removed using the disable : true, but the field isn't grayed out and still is easy to read.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    disabled: true,
    disabledCls: 'x-field',
    label: 'Label',
    name: 'name'
}
```

This could become a simple override if I had enough of these fields and took the time to override the other field types I needed.